# Select all years from 2 date colums

Tags: mysql

it's very simple what I'm trying to do, but no sure if it's posible and if it is how can I do it?

I have a mysql data base with a table what has trackId, StartDate, EndDate and im trying to get all the distinc years from both colums in 1 resultset.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(StartDate) as year, YEAR(EndDate) as year 
from TRACK
```

and my result is :

```
| year | year |
|------|------|
| 2016 | 2017 |
| 2017 | 2018 |
```

And what I'm trying to get is:

```
| year |
|------|
| 2016 |
| 2017 |
| 2018 |
```

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT * from (
   SELECT YEAR(StartDate) as year from TRACK 
   UNION
   SELECT YEAR(EndDate) as year from TRACK 
 )
 ORDER BY year
```

The outer select is only necessary if you need the result in an order way

Comment: Thanks, thats just what I needed!

Comment: @JuanfriLira You are welcome. If it is what you Need, feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Year] From
(SELECT StartYear AS [Year] FROM #Test
UNION
SELECT EndYear AS [Year] FROM #Test) A
```